# large number of databases in postgres - architectural best practices

Tags: node.js, postgresql, architecture, node-postgres

We are using postgres in a multi tenant nodejs set up. Each client has a separate database (and a separate node process). Connection pooling is implemented for each tenant using node-postgres module. Because of the increasing number of databases, we are soon hitting the max_connections limit of postgres. increasing max_connections indefinitely is not an option (due to connection overheads). Should there be a change in the architecture for large number of databases? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you describe cannot scale: the number of databases will always be the limiting factor.

You definitely need to redesign the system. And the correct approach will depend entirely on the project's requirements.

Pointers for designing a system in general - that's a very broad subject. You can start with [Practical Approach to Computer Systems Design and Architecture](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16105/A-Practical-Approach-to-Computer-Systems-Design-an), and from thence research it further, following your project's requirements.